# rewriting reduce method with a function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to rewrite the reduce method with this function. It seems like I'm half way there except it only subtracts the last element in the array from the initialValue(10) how can I make all of the numbers subtract from initialValue?

```
reduce([1, 2, 3], function(total, number) {
  return total - number;
}, 10); // should return 4

function reduce(array,callback,initialValue){
  var sum;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    sum = callback(initialValue,array[i])
  }
 return sum
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the callback with the update sum on each step. The easiest way to make the change would probably to set `sum=initialValue` as below,

```
reduce([1, 2, 3], function(total, number) {
  return total - number;
}, 10); // should return 4

function reduce(array,callback,initialValue){
  var sum = initialValue;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    sum = callback(sum,array[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

initial value might be missing, the more accurate version would be like this:

```
reduce = function(ary, callback, init) {
    var i = 0;
    if (arguments.length < 3)
        init = ary[i++];
    for (; i < ary.length; i++)
        init = callback(init, ary[i], i);
    return init;
}
```

For the version which is 100% conformant to the specs, see the [Mozilla shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You keep passing in `initialValue` to the callback. Instead set `sum` to `initialValue` initially and pass that in to the callback.

Comment: Could you show me an example? Sorry I just cant get my head around this one. Thanks so much

Comment: See the answer @megawac gave, he does exactly that.